# Automatically update a chart in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, charts, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet in which I have data in rows that are added to dynamically via some VBA code. Every minute, a new row of data is added. When the spreadsheet is closed, more code automatically deletes all of this data. When the spreadsheet reopens, the data is refreshed and, again, added to every minute.

I would like to graph this data in a line chart. I want the line chart to update every minute, but I'd also like the X-axis to dynamically 'grow' every minute. To achieve this, I have been using the offset command within 'define name' as follows:

```
Time=OFFSET(Sheet4!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet4!$A:$A)-1)
```

and

```
Total=OFFSET(Sheet4!$K$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet4!$K:$K)-1)
```

Time of day is on the x-axis of my graph and Total is on the y-axis.

Within the chart itself, under Select Data Source, for the x (horizontal) axis, axis label range is set as:

```
=Sheet4!Time
```

And the under Legend Entries, the series values on the are set as:

```
=Sheet4!Total
```

This all works perfectly well UNTIL I close my spreadsheet down and reopen it. The graph is no longer populated with any data, and it does not update each minute. If I go into Name Manager, "Time" now reads as:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet4!#REF!,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet4!$A:$A)-1)
```

and Total reads as:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet4!#REF!,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet4!$K:$K)-1)
```

So, the references have been lost. I suspect this is because when the spreadsheet reopens, it is looking for values in the first row and doesn't find them instantaneously (perhaps it is looking for them BEFORE the VBA code pulls in the data).

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am using Excel 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INDIRECT to work around your macro deleting the lines

```
Time=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet4!$A$2"),0,0,COUNTA(Sheet4!$A:$A)-1)
```

this way the Sheet4!$A$2 is not a cell reference, but a text string, so it doesn't change to #Ref when the cell is deleted. The INDIRECT creates a cell reference so no matter how many cells are deleted it will always point to the A2.

Answer (score 2):

> When the spreadsheet is closed, more code automatically deletes all of
>   this data.

When you delete all the data the cell references are lost - if you reference cell `A1` and then delete that cell any formula will now show a `#REF!` error.
If you clear the contents of the cells rather than delete them the error will never appear.

Somewhere in your code will be a line similar to:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Delete
```

If you change this line to:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents
```

the cells won't be deleted and the `#REF!` error will be avoided.